# How to make Branch SDK send data to an IntentService instead of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice, branch.io

I noticed in the [branch.io documentations](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/) that branch SDK can only be configured to send deep linking data to an `Activity`. These methods must be called to setup branch SDK:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error)
    {
            if (error == null)
            {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

As you see the method `initSession()` only accepts `Activity` for the third input. but I want the deeplinking data be sent to an `IntentService`. Am I missing something and branch provides a way to do that? Or if it doesn't, how can I provide the feature? I know that I can start an invisible activity and pass data through that to the `IntentService` but I've read that it makes the startup slow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have anything baked into the SDK for sending parameters directly to an intent service. Capturing these parameters yourself in an activity and passing them elsewhere won't take more time than any other approach, as all approaches will require an init call, and that's where the negligible delay lives.

Comment: SDK provides a way. I don't know if it's just a misuse or a feature of it. but I tested that and it worked. No need to add any activity.

Comment: Hi Melika. We rely on the activity lifecycle methods to safely return data, just because your intent service works does not mean we can support the approach, or that it will always reliably work. I'm glad you cooked something up, but just a head's up that it's not something we currently support :).

Comment: Oh, I noticed you're one of the contributers of Branch. So it's just a misuse. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I read the source code of Branch and found out that there are some overloaded methods which doesn't get `Activity` as an input. Actually they are calling `initSession` with `Activity` set as `null`.

```
/**
 * <p>Initialises a session with the Branch API.</p>
 *
 * @param callback A {@link BranchReferralInitListener} instance that will be called
 *                 following successful (or unsuccessful) initialisation of the session
 *                 with the Branch API.
 * @param data     A {@link  Uri} variable containing the details of the source link that
 *                 led to this initialisation action.
 * @return A {@link Boolean} value that will return <i>false</i> if the supplied
 * <i>data</i> parameter cannot be handled successfully - i.e. is not of a
 * valid URI format.
 */
public boolean initSession(BranchReferralInitListener callback, @NonNull Uri data) {
    return initSession(callback, data, null);
}
```

I used the method declared above and defined all the needed intent filters inside my `IntentService` declaration in `manifest`, instead of an `activity`. I tested it and it worked. It would be nice if they had documented that.

**UPDATE**

It's just a misuse. Not a reliable and supported approach. It would be better to create an invisible `Activity` and send data through that to the `IntentService`.